# MySQL inconsistent query results in procedure with temp tables (empty resultset)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, temp-tables

I have also posted this question on [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/169320/mysql-inconsistent-query-results-in-procedure-with-temp-tables-empty-resultset), but i'm putting it here too, hoping for more answers.

Our server runs a 10.0.30-MariaDB on a AWS EC2-instance. We have a stored procedure which creates multiple temp tables, joins between them and eventually produce a final result. When we call this procedure the first time (in a new connection), we always get a result. If we call this procedure again, but with different parameters, our resultset is always empty for that connection. If we start a new connection and do the second call again, now this call will return the correct result, but the first call will be empty. See simplified scheme below:

```
Connection 1:
call my_procedure("a"); > 1 row returned
call my_procedure("b"); > 0 rows returned
call my_procedure("a"); > 1 row returned

Connection 2:
call my_procedure("b"); > 1 row returned
call my_procedure("a"); > 0 rows returned
call my_procedure("b"); > 1 row returned
```

We can always reproduce this behaviour this way.

Also, when we change the procedure (even by just adding a comment), the next call reacts as if called on a new connection. So if we first call "a", we get result, but "b" will never work and visa-versa.

Our procedure is valid sql and returns correct data, temp tables get properly cleared, ... but for some reason returns no data at certain occasions.

We get the impression we hit some internal 'limitation' or so. We've already tried various things, but we're getting out of options where to look or how to debug.

Any advice on how to debug such a situation is welcome.

See below for the procedure. I've simplified it down a bit. On the dba.stackexchange post you can see an alternative full version:

```
PROCEDURE `select_products`(IN arg_uuid VARCHAR(36),
                            IN arg_application VARCHAR(36),
                            IN arg_app_version VARCHAR(20),
                            IN arg_installation VARCHAR(50),
                            IN arg_user VARCHAR(36),
                            IN arg_product VARCHAR(36),
                            IN arg_license VARCHAR(36),
                            IN arg_type VARCHAR(10),
                            IN arg_code VARCHAR(255),
                            IN arg_group VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

  DECLARE var_b_user INT DEFAULT NULL; 

  SET var_b_user = (select bu.id from b_user bu JOIN user u on u.id = bu.user where u.`key` = arg_user limit 1);


  /********************* PLTA **********************/

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS plta;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE plta (product_id INT, license_id INT, token_id INT, activation_id INT, INDEX(product_id, license_id))
  SELECT
    l.product as product_id, l.id as license_id, lt.token as token_id, null as activation_id
  FROM
    license l,
    license_token lt,
    activation a,
    `user` u
  WHERE
        a.current = TRUE
    AND l.id = lt.license
    AND a.`user` = u.id
    AND a.installation = arg_installation
    AND u.`key` = arg_user
    AND lt.token = a.token
    group by product_id, license_id, token_id;

    UPDATE plta, activation a, `user` u
    SET activation_id = a.id
    WHERE
        u.id = a.user
    and a.current = TRUE
    AND u.`key` = arg_user
    AND a.installation = arg_installation
    AND a.license = plta.license_id
    AND a.token = plta.token_id;


  /********************* TMP_PP **********************/

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_pp;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_pp (product INT,INDEX(product))
  SELECT DISTINCT
    p.id AS product
  FROM
    product p
  JOIN
    application n
  ON
       p.application = n.id
   AND n.`key` = arg_application
  LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        gp.product
      FROM
        product_group__product gp,
        product_group g
      WHERE
            gp.enabled = TRUE
        AND gp.product_group = g.id
        AND g.`key` = arg_group
     ) g
   ON
     p.id = g.product

  WHERE
        (   p.`key` = arg_product
         OR (    arg_product IS NULL
             AND p.enabled = TRUE))
    AND (   g.product IS NOT NULL
         OR arg_group IS NULL)
    AND (   p.app_version IS NULL
         OR arg_app_version IS NULL
         OR (INET_ATON(p.app_version) <= INET_ATON(arg_app_version)));

  select * from tmp_pp;


  /********************* TMP_LT **********************/

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_lt;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_lt (license INT,token INT,INDEX(license),INDEX(token))
    SELECT
      lt.license,
      t.id as token
    FROM
      license_token lt,
      token t
    WHERE
          lt.token = t.id
      AND t.`type` = arg_type
      AND (  (    arg_code IS NOT NULL
              AND t.code = arg_code)
           OR arg_type = 'free');


  select * from tmp_lt;


  /********************* PLT_PROD **********************/

  SELECT
    p.id AS product,
    l.id AS license,
    tmp_lt.token,
    NULL AS activation,
    FALSE AS license_auto_activation
  FROM
    product p
  JOIN
    tmp_pp
  ON
    p.id = tmp_pp.product
  JOIN
    license l
  ON
        (   l.`key` = arg_license 
         OR arg_license IS NULL)
    AND l.enabled = TRUE
    AND l.product = p.id
    AND (   l.app_version IS NULL
         OR arg_app_version IS NULL
         OR (INET_ATON(l.app_version) <= INET_ATON(arg_app_version))) 
  LEFT JOIN
    tmp_lt
  ON
    l.id = tmp_lt.license  
  WHERE
     (   arg_type IS NULL
         OR arg_type = 'auto'
         OR tmp_lt.token IS NOT NULL);

END
```

Also 'funny' to note is that if we change the last WHERE to simply `WHERE arg_type = 'auto';` this issues no long occurs (although the result is not the same of course).

Comment: I had a similar issue with temp tables; can post your stored procedure code?

Comment: @dsharew: I added the code to my original question.

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB?

Comment: It is likely that you have hit the bug, 2nd execution of PS/SP is historically notoriously unreliable. Please file a JIRA issue at jira.mariadb.org . Unless you can narrow it down on your side, please provide definitions of all involved objects (or better still, the schema dump).

Comment: @RickJames: version is 10.0.30-MariaDB, but on MariaDB 5.5.54 we have the same issue. We hit this issue after server migration. Before we were on a private hosting with MariaDB 5.5.22 and there everything worked fine. I don't know if this issue is due to the change in MariaDB version or change in hardware/software on the new server or if we are missing some crucial settings...

Comment: What is `x`?  (very near the end of the SP)

Comment: typo... sorry. Changed it to tmp_lt

Comment: Currently we're circumventing the issue by changing back to MySQL instead of MariaDB. MySQL Community Edition 5.6  doesn't have this issue, so I guess it specific MariaDB. I try to narrow it down and post it on jira.mariadb.org as @elenst suggested.

Comment: Here's an issue on the mariadb bug tracker that seems to be about the very same issue: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15035